# Why does the Origami Killer leave his victims near railroad tracks?

Tags: heavy-rain

At the beginning of the game, Jayden learns that the Origami Killer always leaves the corpses of his victims near railroad tracks.

I never found an in-game explanation for why the killer did this.

**Was this just a red herring for the police or was there a clue somewhere in game that I didn't uncover?**

Comment: What? Who? I was at a friend's house.  No more questions.

Comment: If you think he'll "fold" so easily you're sadly mistaken, sir!

Comment: I seem to recall it mentioning something that wasn't quite a red herring, but which didn't end up being very relevant and so was kinda forgettable (so, more a false lead)—something like e.g. covering any noise—but I don't actually remember the detail.